# Ubermenu item is not clickable after submenu added

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I added BLOG submenu under the NEWS menu [here](http://catphones.ge/en) and NEWS link is not clickable any more and as a result, the cursor image has disappeared.

Ubermenu support doesn't work on weekends, but I can't wait. 
Any solution?!

Answer (score 1):

Your a tag has a

html:

`class="not-clickable-item"` and `href="http://#"` on it.

css code:

```
.not-clickable-item {
    cursor: default;
}
```

The parent link items that link to actual pages are fine

Comment: It's strange, because, it is not a custom links item, it's category item.So, I don't understand, why it has these tags.

Comment: But the the news parent link item doesn't work for me.